# How to calculate score out of 1000 given some seconds (In Double)

Tags: ios, swift, time

I want to calculate a score out of 1000 based on some seconds that was given to me. The score should be high if seconds is a small value and it should be low if seconds is a large value.

For eg. If a folder A was accessed 30 secs ago and folder B was accessed 500 secs ago then score of folder A should be higher compared to score of folder B since folder A is the one that was recently accessed compared to folder B. The score cannot exceed more than 1000.

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn’t a free code writing service you know.

Comment: Do you try to make it by your self?

Comment: There are many such functions. One possible method is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay

Comment: @MartinR Maybe a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) would be better?

Comment: @Sweeper: We cannot know – the requirements are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do in a simple way is to multiply the numbers by -1 so you get negative values on both sides and then you can start comparing them.
Example :

- folder A was accessed 30 secs
- folder B was accessed 500 secs

And you want folder A to be a higher value than Folder B

so :

A = (30 * -1) = -30 sec

B = (500 * -1) = -500 sec

so comparing:  A > B

And then add a condition where the score cannot exceed 1000.